# making reference to file two by two in a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, loops, file, for-loop

I have this list of file that I have to analyse by pair (the a_1 with a_2, b_1 with b_2 and so on)

```
a_1.fq
a_2.fq
b_1.fq
b_2.fq
c_1.fq
...
```

I want to set a for loop to make reference to these pairs of file in a command, bellow
this is just an example of what I want to do (with a false syntax) :

```
$ for File1 File2 in *1.fq *2.fq; do STAR --readFilein File1 File2 ; done
```

Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: bash has no real support for processing pairs. You could instead create two arrays of equal size, with the idea that elements at corresponding positions refer to such a pair, and then loop over the index. Another possibility would be to create one associative array, where the key is a file name from the one set, and its value is the corresponding (paired) file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function to process pairs and iterate the glob expansion:

```sh
process_pair()
{
  while [ $# -gt 0 ]
  do
    f1=$1 # get 1st argument
    shift # shift to next argument
    f2=$1 # get 2nd argument
    shift # shift to next for the next round

    # Do stuffs with file1 and file2
    printf 'f1=%s\tf2=%s\n' "$f1" "$f2"
  done
}

# Submit pattern expansion as process_pair arguments
process_pair ./*_[12].fq
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over just one type of the files and use parameter expansion to device the second one:

```sh
for file1 in *1.fq; do
    file2=${file1%1.fq}2.fq
    ...
```

The `%pattern` removes the pattern from the end of the variable's value.

You might want to check for the file2's existence before running the command.

Or, if you can get the files listed in the way the pairs are adjacent, you can populate `$@` with them and `shift` the parameters by two:

```sh
set -- [a-z]_[12].fq
while (( $# )) ; do
    file1=$1
    file2=$2
    shift 2
    ...
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much it seems very simple, and can I write the command right after ? like for file1 in *1.fq; do file2=${file1%1.fq}2.fq STAR --readFilein File1 File2

Comment: Yes, just replace the `...` with the command.

Comment: I tryied your solution but the file2 do not show up in the commande line validation as if it was not created : for file1 in *1.fq; do file2=${file1%1.fq}2.fq STAR --readFilesIn ${file1} ${file2}  --outFileNamePrefix ${file1%1.fq}; done           do you know why ?

Comment: Try running the script with `set -xv` to see what's really happening, or prepend `echo` to `STAR` to check what commands are going to be run.

Comment: STAR --readFilesIn a_114_1.fq --outFileNamePrefix a_114_
STAR --readFilesIn a_1901_1.fq --outFileNamePrefix a_1901_

Comment: This is the echo, he map well the file1 even for the prefix but seems that it didn't create the file2

Comment: Do you have `#!/bin/bash` on the first line? How do you run the script? What version of bash do you run?

Comment: Maybe you missed a semicolon after an assignment in the command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
for letter in {a..z}
do
 # Your logic
  echo "Working on $letter"
  cat $letter\_1.fq
  cat $letter\_2.fq
done
```